# Shooting For a Star Supervisor VS Mediocre Supervisor and Consequences For Your Academic Life Career

Tags: research-process, advisor, supervision

I have asked this question before, but it seems easier said than done. I think this question is really important for prospective students for making a sound decision for their career life. Academia, in general, is very competitive. My question is: If your goal to be recognized in your research field, should you shoot a star researcher in your field and wait maybe a couple of years to join his/her lab, or working with a mediocre supervisor and in that case, I have to build a reputation on my own, however, I don't know whether it possible.

Definitely, we cannot make a sweeping generalization, but some stars in the field are really bully and this based on true starts( happened to me and others posts here) and they can write pretty bad letters.

Should a prospective student wait to shoot a star lab/supervisor or just manage to finish and then build his/her reputation by attending conferences, organizing workshops.

**EDIT**

I have been shortlisted as top candidates at a very prestigious institute in Europe, however, the junior supervisor selected me is really negative person based on a couple of discussions and ignoring multiple emails, I cannot imagine myself to be his student.

On the other hand, another supervisor is quite old, not so much involved in research, but he offered to deposit a grant for next year. He is really very nice person, his former student was able to finish, but he told me you will learn on your own.

I don't have many options cause I am running out financially and has no many options, maybe I am not a lucky person.

Comment: As it stands, your question is OT, since only you can really answer it. Can you make the question less about you and more generic?

Comment: I did, hope it is fine.

Comment: Students shouldn't shoot any supervisor, star or otherwise... can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: It's not a dichotomy: A supervisor can be a non-star without being mediocre.

Comment: @astronat, how the student shouldn't shoot any supervisor, you must consider with whom you are growing to commit to making your career grows properly. Being with a poor supervisor whether in personal or professional is deteriorating your career, and that was my previous case, so I want to make this time good decision hopefully.

Comment: "shoot for" = "try for"

Comment: @Monika do you perhaps mean "choosing a star supervisor", or "shooting **for** a star supervisor"? Presumably, as astronaut notes, you don't mean shooting them (as in firing a gun). If anything, that would make it difficult to join their lab later...

Answer (score 5):

It feels to me that you are describing a false dichotomy. You will in fact need a supervisor who is both competent *and* with whom you are able to have at least a professional relationship. However, I don't really believe that your supervisor needs to be a "shooting star" - a regular, competent, research-active professor should do just fine.

Surely not *all* competent academics in your field are jerks / bullies? If they indeed are, I worry that your expectations are in some dimension unreasonable.

Comment: I am sorry for not be a good writer, I cannot deliver my message properly.